# use msdeploy to install a zip-package on a remote computer from commandline

Tags: msdeploy

I have a .zip package that I want to install on a development server from my development machine. So I use the msdeploy to do this automatic for me.

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:package=Debug_Services_14.02.20.1413.zip -dest:auto,computername=DEVELOPMENTSERVER,username=ADMIN_USER,password=ADMIN_PWD
```

But it fails saying that the ERROR_SITE_DOESNT_EXIST.

```
Info: Adding sitemanifest (sitemanifest).
Info: Adding createApp (MY_SERVICE).
Info: Adding contentPath (MY_SERVICE).
Error Code: ERROR_SITE_DOES_NOT_EXIST
More Information: Site MY_SERVICE does not exist.  Learn more at: http
://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SITE_DOES_NOT_EXIST.
Error count: 1.
```

But I am trying to install it for the first time! What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

For example. msdeploy api c#.
[Execute MSDeploy from C# program code like an API](http://tech.en.tanaka733.net/entry/msdeploy-from-csharp)

```
public static void AppSynchronization(DeploymentBaseOptions depBaseOptions, string       appPath)
{
    var deploymentObjectSyncApp = DeploymentManager.CreateObject(
        DeploymentWellKnownProvider.Package,
        appPath, new DeploymentBaseOptions());

    deploymentObjectSyncApp.SyncTo(DeploymentWellKnownProvider.Auto, string.Empty,
        depBaseOptions, new DeploymentSyncOptions());
}
```

where

```
var deployBaseOptions = new DeploymentBaseOptions
            {
                ComputerName = @"https://WIN-CCDDFDFDFD:8172/msdeploy.axd",
                UserName = @"WIN-CCDDFDFDFD\Al",
                Password = "1212121",
                AuthenticationType = "Basic"
            };
appPath = "C:\mySite.zip";
```